# How to fill missing values in a loop using conditions in julia?

Tags: julia, fill

I would like to check the loop for number of items and then if the items are of not expected size then fill it with 0's. For example, I have created a loop which tries to access an array's elements for a range of 10

```
x = range(1, 100, length=45) |> collect
n = trunc(Int, length(x)/10) + 1
s = 1
l = 10
for i in 1:n
    print(x[s:l])
    s += 10
    l +=10
end
```

In the above code, last iteration doesn't print any result as the number of elements are only 5 but it expects it to be 10. Hence, I would like to know, how may i check in this loop for every iteration the number of elements and if they are not expected then fill it with 0's.

Please suggest and advise on achieving the expected operation.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should share what is your goal because your code reminds me of the `Iterators.partition` pattern. You can split an iterator into chuncks of size 10 even when the division is not perfect: `Iterators.partition(x, 10) |> collect`. Is that what you want in the end? Take a look in the standard Iibrary of Iterators, there may be something useful there for your use case.

Comment: @juliohm thanks for the response!! Actually, I have huge arrays of almost 10,000+ elements. And part of this array is fed to perform mathematical operation, which is enclosed in a loop. Hence, my initial approach was to use the for loop to do these operation. However, if the arrays are not evenly distributed then loop returns an error of dimension mismatching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `PaddedViews` is what you are looking for:

```
julia> using PaddedViews

julia> PaddedView(0, x, (ceil(Int, length(x)/10)*10,))
50-element PaddedView(0.0, ::Vector{Float64}, (Base.OneTo(50),)) with eltype Float64:
   1.0
   3.25
   5.5
   7.75
  10.0
  12.25
  14.5
  16.75
   ⋮
  97.75
 100.0
   0.0
   0.0
   0.0
   0.0
   0.0
```